# How to make this frame around my sections fullwidth?

Tags: sectioning, framed

The code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor} 

\makeatletter
\def\section{\@ifstar\unnumberedsection\numberedsection}
\def\numberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \numberedsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\unnumberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\numberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\ifhmode\par\fi
%\removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \colorbox{yellow}{%
      \hbox to 1cm{\hss\bfseries\Large\thesection \ \ }%
      \vtop{%
        \advance \hsize by 8cm
        \advance \hsize by -2\fboxrule
        \advance \hsize by 2\fboxsep
        \parindent=0pt
        \leavevmode\raggedright\bfseries\Large
       \strut\strut \linespread{1.4}\selectfont#2
       \noindent
        }%
      }
      }\nobreak
  \vskip 5mm\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \hspace*{1mm}\protect\numberline{\thesection}%
    #1}%
    \noindent
    \sectionmark{#1}%
  \ignorespaces%
}

\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\section{A  Test}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

gives me this output:

[image]

but I want the frame to be fullwidth like the following. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This quick change makes the trick:

Just replace

```
\hbox to \hsize{%
\colorbox{yellow}{%
\hbox to 1cm{\hss\bfseries\Large\thesection \ \ }%
```

with

```
\hspace{-4cm}
\hbox to \hsize{%
\colorbox{yellow}{%
\hbox to 5cm{\hss\bfseries\Large\thesection \ \ }%
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works!

[image: Example]